# mysql converter tool doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to run the mysqli converter tool (https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi) to convert some old mysql cod to mysqli format.

Whenver I run the tool from the command line it just spits back the same code as the original file and doesn't find anything to change. Even doing this:

```
php cli.php -s "mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');" -v
- Summary ----------------------------------------------------------------------

Status: OK
Number of mysql_-functions found: 0
Number of mysql_-functions converted: 0
Warnings/Errors: 0
Code length: 38 Bytes


- Generated code ---------------------------------------------------------------

mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');

- End of code ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

doesn't find anything to convert, which it should find mysql_connect at least. Am I missing something? Does this not work anymore? I ran it through PHP 5.4.16.

Comment: Try `php cli.php -s "<?php mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');" -v` with the opening PHP tag in your codeline

Comment: It parses PHP, anything outside of those tags are assumed to be HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, turns out I was using short_open_tags and the computer I was running the php cli through had those turned off. I enabled them and all works.